# Set bash automatically when connect via ssh

Tags: 14.04, bash, ssh

I have bash when I do login by root user to system. I have something different when do login with another user via ssh. Command line contains symbol `$`. What is that and how to ask system to use bash when login with not root user?

Comment: are you certain this is not `bash` ? What is the output of `echo "$SHELL"` ?

Comment: it is /bin/sh .

Answer (score 1):

The name of this symbol is a **prompt**. It is how the command processor tells you that it is ready to start processing a new command.

Normal users get a '$' prompt. The root user gets a '#' prompt. Most likely, you got bash running in both cases, unless the system administrator or someone else has changed the command processor for that user.

If the command processor is not bash, you can change it by editing the file '/etc/passwd', or by using your distribution's GUI to edit user data.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change your default shell with the command `chsh`.
I suggest you to first read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh) anyway.